# API for TPS and other cluster stats?

Tags: solana

Is there any API that I can call to get the current cluster stats for mainnet or any cluster in fact?

I saw on the Solana Explorer source code that they are calculating it manually, but I was kinda hoping there would be an API as well?

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/explorer/src/components/TpsCard.tsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you'll want https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getrecentperformancesamples, and you can even see how it's being used in the Solana Explorer.

With curl, you can do:

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method":"getRecentPerformanceSamples", "params": [1]}
'
```

Which gives:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "numSlots": 126,
      "numTransactions": 126,
      "samplePeriodSecs": 60,
      "slot": 348125
    }
}
```

Then you can figure out TPS by doing `numTransactions / samplePeriodSecs`.

Reference code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/6d1b6bdd7cff9a4404d00811825493ed5ac1b074/explorer/src/providers/stats/solanaClusterStats.tsx#L105

Answer (score 1):

There's no API endpoint for getting Solana cluster stats such as TPS today.

You can calculate it be using [`getBlock`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblock) and using the list of transactions over time to get TPS.

Answer (score 0):

No API still, but I managed to scrape the TPS from here for my web3 project: https://explorer.solana.com/

Complete Python code for testing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

web = webdriver.Chrome()

web.get(f'https://explorer.solana.com/')
get_solana_status = WebDriverWait(web,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"))).text
solana_status_comma = get_solana_status.replace(",", " ")
solana_status = "".join(solana_status_comma.split())

print(solana_status)
```

Please note, you may need to relocate the XPATH if an exception is raised as it will be likely that the web page will have changed: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html